# Find relationship by id

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I'm trying to delete a managed solution in my CRM "PowerMailChimp" but I get the error below whenever I try to delete the solution.

> Cannot delete Attribute with id 56d0dec2-0061-e511-80e0-3863bb347ba8
>   because a Relationship with id e7a8ac27-fc65-4a43-9f6d-1bc6645f7749
>   exists that relates to this Attribute and delete cascade is
>   restricted

I've spent hours trying to hunt down that relationship in my PowerMailChimp solution but I couldn't find it, I could have missed it.

My question is, is there some way to query all the relationships in the CRM to be able to know the related entities having this relationship id?

Comment: You can ask Microsoft to give you the database backup, and try to find it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe quicker to use the SDK to get the relationship with that Id:

```
//Retrieve the One-to-many relationship using the MetadataId.
RetrieveRelationshipRequest retrieveOneToManyRequest =
                    new RetrieveRelationshipRequest { MetadataId = "the id above" };
RetrieveRelationshipResponse retrieveOneToManyResponse = (RetrieveRelationshipResponse)_serviceProxy.Execute(retrieveOneToManyRequest);
```

More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509021.aspx)